# Can someone spot my error (autocomplete text box)?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So far I have HTML:

```
<div id="box" style="width:400; height:400; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:100;">
<h2>Enter a word</h2>
<input type="text" id="input" ></input>
</div>
<div id="suggest">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#input").keyup(function(){
var input = $("#input").val();
$.ajax({
url: "PathToPHPFileThatConnectsToDatabaseAndRetreivesValues",
data: "input"+input,
success: function(msg){
alert(msg);
$("#suggest").html(msg);
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$dbh=mysql_connect ("localhost", "~", "~") or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db ("~") or ("Database not found");

$input = $_REQUEST['input'];

$input = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($input));

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ~ WHERE ~ LIKE '%".$input."%'";

    $data = mysql_query($sql);

    $arrcnt = -1;

    $dataArray = array();

    while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) 
        {
            foreach($temp as $key=>$val) {
                $temp[$key] = stripslashes($val);
                $arrcnt++;
        }
        $dataarray[$arrcnt] = $temp;
    }

    $list = "<ul style='width:100;height:auto;'>";

    foreach($dataArray as $val) {
        $list .= "<li>".$val['DesiredColumnContainingDesiredData']."</li>";
    }

    $list .= "</ul>";

    echo $list;



?>
```

Now, these codes are supposed to work together to autocomplete the div with id="suggest" then populate the text field with id="input" when selected ... I keep getting alert that reads: `<ul style='width:100;height:auto;'></ul>`

Comment: you need to add it in this manner data: "input="+input

Comment: same alert is appearing ...

Comment: can you do a echo exit near your query and check your query also print your post array . print_r($_POST)

Comment: array is printing empty ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is because in php your variable name is different . You added $dataarray instead of $dataArray

Additionally for ajax

You can  pass data as a string or as an object

data:{"input":input}

or

data:"input="+input

add type: 'POST' in ajax

Comment: added it, print_r($POST) is now only returning what I type ... for example, if I type the letter "a", "Array ( [input] => a )" is printed ... if I continue with "ab", "Array ( [input] => ab )" is printed, however it doesn't seem to be retrieving the values from my database I'm seeking with my query ...

Comment: Echo your query  and check in the mysql console  to see if it is returning values

Comment: echoing "Resource id #3"

Comment: dont echo query result but the query variable $query and then check in mysql console if ihe query is generating results or add this mysql_num_rows($data) and check the value

Comment: got it this is the issue $dataarray[$arrcnt] = $temp; the variable name should be dataArray

Comment: should all of the $temp variables be "dataArray"?

Comment: did you change this line $dataarray[$arrcnt] = $temp; to $dataArray[$arrcnt]

Comment: I changed it to "$dataarray[$arrcnt] = $dataArray;"

Comment: can you add this $queryCount = mysql_num_rows($data) after  this line $data = mysql_query($sql) and check the value of $queryCount

Comment: Yes! It works now! I changed "$dataarray[$arrcnt] = $temp;" to "$dataArray[$arrcnt] = $temp;" ... thank you for helping me troubleshoot rahulinaction!

Answer (score 1):

change ajax code like this,

```
$.ajax({
url: "PathToPHPFileThatConnectsToDatabaseAndRetreivesValues",
data: {"input":input},
success: function(msg){
alert(msg);
$("#suggest").html(msg);
}
});
```